# Prove that the sum of lengths of two segments is minimum if point $M$ ....

Tags: geometry

Two points $A$ and $B$ are in the same semi-plan(take into consideration the line $d$), and their position is arbitrary. Point $A_1$ is the reflection of $A$. Prove that the sum of distances $MA+MB$ is minimum if point $M$(M is an arbitrary point on line $d$) belongs to $BA_1$ .

By intuition I suppose that I somehow have to prove that the measure of angle between the segments $AM$ and $MB$ is $90$ degree, but I don't have any idea. I hope you'll help me find the solution. Thank you!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between the segments $\overline{AM}$ and $\overline{MB}$ doesn't have to be $90^\circ$. Use that the straight line between two points is the shortest path betweeen them and that the distances from $M$ to $A$ and $A_1$ are the same.

Comment: So that's the whole problem?

Comment: @JohnG. Yes, that's it.

Comment: @JohnG. You're welcome.

Comment: Just found this. One way to prove what @Zircht said is by contradiction. Consider another point $P$ on the line d. We obtain triangle $A_1PB$. Use the property that the sum of any two sides of a triangle is always greater than the third side

Answer (score 1):

This is the so-called **Heron's Problem**.

For anyone finding the existing answers unhelpful, I found a great explanation here:
https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/HeronsProblem.shtml